# Label block quote like displayed equation

Tags: equations, csquotes

I would like to be able to add a tag to a block quote in a more or less identical manner as one would with a displayed question.  Ideally, I would also be able to use `\label` and `\eqref` (or `\ref`) as if they quote were actually an equation.

You might say that I would like to combine the functionality of the below two examples.  Is there a simple way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

This is a displayed quote.
\begin{displayquote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{displayquote}
That was a displayed quote.

\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is how I would like to label my block quote.
\begin{equation}
\tag{A}3x^2+1=5.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Block quote]
[image: Displayed equation]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set *anything* inside an equation, including a `\parbox` (or other textual components like a `minipage` or `tabular`). Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is a displayed quote.
\begin{equation}
  \tag{A}\label{eq:A}
  \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-4em}{%
    \strut
    \lipsum*[1]%
    \strut
  }
\end{equation}
That was a displayed quote~\eqref{eq:A}.
This is how I would like to label my block quote~\eqref{eq:B}:
\begin{equation}
  3x^2 + 1 = 5.\label{eq:B}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Depending on the textual content inside the `equation`, you may want to add `\strut`s to achieve an appropriate baseline skip.

Note that this "quote" will not break across the page boundary, similar to an equation.

Comment: What about using `\allowdisplaybreaks`?

Comment: @Astrinus: Not if you are using `\parbox` (or `minipage` or `tabular`), as this boxes the content so it is set as a unit. It would be weird to have it broken across the page boundary though, a paragraph I mean. Where would you put the tag? I guess one could set it a little differently and allow breaking in some form of list (that's LaTeX-speak for allowing breaks across the page boundary), but I'm not sure what is to be gained from it.

Comment: I wasn't sure it could be used, looking at your reputation made me ask that question. Thanks a lot for the explanation!